# Android rate button syntax errors

Tags: java, android

I get the errors Syntax error on token "marketrate", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token... Uri.parse("https://market.android.com/details?id=com.synamegames.giveaway");

and

Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)...startActivity(market);

```
        private void makeDialog() {     

        AlertDialog.Builder about = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);      

        about.setMessage("About The Giveaway");

        about.setPositiveButton("Rate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            Intent market = new Intent(
                    "android.intent.action.VIEW", 

                startActivity(market);
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
//action
            }
        });

        about.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {}
        });

        about.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this,
 I had tested the code and working as per requirement..

AlertDialog.Builder about = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

```
    about.setMessage("About The Giveaway");

    about.setPositiveButton("Rate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        Intent market = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",Uri.parse("https://market.android.com/details?id=com.synamegames.giveaway"));

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
        {
                    //action
            startActivity(market);  

        }
    });

    about.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
        {

        }
    });

    about.show();
```

try to run the code in Main/UI Thread.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got two problems.

First, you've got mismatched brackets here:

```
Intent market = new Intent(
    "android.intent.action.VIEW", 
    Uri.parse("https://market.android.com/details?id=com.synamegames.giveaway");
startActivity(market);
```

I think you need an extract bracket after the `Uri.parse` call, to close the Intent constructor call:

```
Intent market = new Intent(
    "android.intent.action.VIEW", 
    Uri.parse("https://market.android.com/details?id=com.synamegames.giveaway"));
startActivity(market);
```

Or extract the `Uri.parse` call out to start with:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://market.android.com/details?id=com.synamegames.giveaway");
Intent market = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri);
startActivity(market);
```

Second, you've got effectively a block of code in your `OnClickListener()` inner subclass, not in an initializer block or a method. Did you mean to put it in the `onClick` handler?

```
about.setPositiveButton("Rate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("...");
        Intent market = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri);
        startActivity(market);
    }
});
```